# Pagamento por cartão android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de comprar de lanches e necessito vender com cartão de credito comecei a observar a API da pagseguro e estou com as seguintes duvidas :

- Ela e a melhor api para integrar ?
- Necessito de alguma iso ou pagamento para integrar ?
- Quais os pre requezitos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A melhor Api para integrar é meio relativo, a melhor é a que da menos
  trabalho? Que tem a menor taxa ?
- Não achei nada na documentação sobre pagamento/taxa para integrar,
  então provavelmente você vai pagar só a porcentagem de cada cobrança.
- Eles tem umas bibliotecas para facilitar a integração, pelo que vi a
  de java tem requisitos: Java 1.6+, Gradle (somente para editar o
  código-fonte deste SDK)

Fontes:

- https://devs.pagseguro.uol.com.br/docs/bibliotecas-java
- https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/guia-de-integracao/api-de-pagamentos.html#!rmcl
- Biblioteca java : https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-java-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Cara use a cielo!
Ele tem bastante bandeira e funciona direitinho.
Existe o script para pagamento com cartão de crédito pronto!

Neste link está tudo pronto e você vai ter que ficar esquentando cabeça.

Dá uma olhada.

Exemplo funcionando:

https://datafacilinformatica.com.br/script-em-php-para-pagamento-com-cartao-de-creditos/

https://www.datafacilinformatica.com.br/venda/script-para-integraco-com-cielo-php-cielo-ecommerce.php

Espero ter ajudado.